# convert time in seconds in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time

I've got time 2014-01-01 06:31:00 UTC.

from above time format I need to extract 06:31:00 in seconds except year:month:date

i.e 2014-01-01 06:31:00 should return 6*60*60+31*60=23460 seconds,

what is the best approach for this

Comment: 6 × 60 × 60 + 31 × 60 = 23460

Comment: Those new to SO often don't realize they are expected to select an answer, provided at least one was helpful to you.

Answer (score 9):

Rails provides `Time#seconds_since_midnight`:

```
time = Time.parse("2014-01-01 06:31:00 UTC")

time.seconds_since_midnight
#=> 23460.0
```